# How to secure actuator endpoints with role in Spring Boot 2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

Can you help to secure actuator endpoints in Spring Boot 2? I checked migration guide but it doesn't help me.

Here is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ADMIN")    
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

but when I go to `http://localhost:8080/actuator/health` it loads without login. Other endpoints with prefix `/actuator` doesn't require login as well. What I did wrong?

I also add OAuth with this configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .inMemory()
                .withClient("client-id")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                    .secret("xxxxxx")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(6000);
}
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ajax/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: @DennisGlot I started new projects, this is first config :/ I just have userService and password encoder added in configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)

Comment: @DenisStephanov Do you have all configuration in one application? AFAIR then the order of your configuation is `AuthorizationServerConfig` (only OAuth2 endpoints), `ResourceServerConfig` (all endpoints) and `SecConfig` (never used).

Comment: @DenisStephanov You have to restrict your resource configuration. You could for example add `.antMatcher("/ajax/**")` to your resource server configuration to only apply the configuration for `/ajax/**` and not for `/actuator`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your application is a resource server you don't need the SecConfig class.

So if you remove it, in your `ResourceServerConfig` class you can secure the actuators and just let admin through:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ajax/**").authenticated()           
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ADMIN")  
                .anyRequest().authenticated()  
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

I add `.anyRequest().authenticated()` to secure the rest of the application endpoints.

Comment: Recommended this for mentioning a solution based on Resource Server and Authorization Server

Comment: I tried it and it looks it works, thank you. But is it a way how to do in spring boot 2? I thought it is boot 1.5x

Comment: Yes, is spring boot 2, the configuration of HttpSecurity does not change much. All the tests of this example those made with version 2.1.x.

Answer (score 2):

you can try below configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ACTUATOR")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
}
```

Verify that you have the following in the application.properties:

```
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=pass
spring.security.user.roles=ACTUATOR,USER   # or any other role 
management.endpoint.health.roles=ACTUATOR
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me ... I tried also add deny all endpoints to test my security but it doesn't have any affect for that :/ something is wrong but I don't know what

Comment: @DenisStephanov https://github.com/andifalk/actuator-security-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/actuator/security/ActuatorSecurityConfig.java  I referred to this and verified it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class ActuatorSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("configuring actuator security");
        // secure actuator endpoints with with ADMIN role
        http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");
        // but publicly allow the health endpoint
        http.requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
    }
}
```

See also the example from in the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.security:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MySecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
                .authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().hasRole("ENDPOINT_ADMIN"));
        http.httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

In this last example be aware that Spring Boot’s security configuration *backs off completely* in the presence of any `SecurityFilterChain` bean.